# SQL case in order by

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, case

I am trying to order by year ascending/descending however I want when the year is 0 to be treated as the newest.

For example:

```
 2013
 2014
 0

 ORDER BY YEAR DESC should be

 0
 2014
 2013
```

After some reading I thought this should work but it doesn't:

```
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN YEAR = 0 THEN 9999, YEAR ASC
```

Comment: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN YEAR = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`

Comment: `CASE WHEN x THEN y ELSE z END`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
select  * 
from TableName
order by case YEAR when 0 then 9999 else YEAR end desc
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f977e/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName
ORDER BY CASE WHEN YEAR = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, YEAR ASC
```

Result:

```
YEAR
0
2013
2014
```

An example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3018c/1).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

> SELECT *
>   FROM TableName
>   ORDER BY IF( YEAR =0, 9999, YEAR ) DESC